# Efficiently summing outer product for 1D NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I have a function of the form

[image]

One way to implement this function in numpy is to assemble a matrix to sum over:

```
y = a*b - np.sum(np.outer(a*b, b), axis=0)
```

Is there a better way to implement this function with numpy, one that doesn't involve creating an NxN array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
y = a*b - np.einsum('i,i,j->j',a,b,b)
```

We can also perform `a*b` and feed to `einsum`  -

```
y = a*b - np.einsum('i,j->j',a*b,b)
```

On the second approach, we can save some runtime by storing `a*b` and reusing.

Runtime test -

```
In [253]: a = np.random.rand(4000)

In [254]: b = np.random.rand(4000)

In [255]: %timeit np.sum(np.outer(a*b, b), axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [256]: %timeit np.einsum('i,i,j->j',a,b,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 24.2 ms per loop

In [257]: %timeit np.einsum('i,j->j',a*b,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: @reptilicus That's the perfect way to describe it! :)

Comment: bah, my comment was deleted. Alas, the censors have my number

Comment: @reptilicus Haha, some kid AI-bot at work probably ;)